# Laravel 5 eloquent model won't let me update

Tags: php, laravel

I do have the invitations table set up and in the database. I use it for other purpose such as adding more...

my goal: update the first record with a new value to a field:

I tried:

```
$invitation = new MemberInvitation();
$invitation1 = $invitation->find(1);
$invitation1->status = 'clicked';
$invitation1->save();
```

And also:

```
$invitation1 = \App\Model\MemberInvitation::find(1);
$invitation1->status = 'clicked';
$invitation1->save();
```

both ended with:

```
Creating default object from empty value
```

EDIT:

This piece of code worked and updated my records correctly -- I just can't do it via Eloquent's model:

```
\DB::table('member_invitations')->where('id', '=', $member_invitation->id)
                    ->update(array('status' => 'clicked', 'member_id' => $member->id));
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Is there actually a first record? Typically you'd get that if `find(1)` didn't return a record. Try `findOrFail` instead of `find` and see if it throws an exception.

Comment: This worked: __\DB::table('member_invitations')->where('id', '=', $member_invitation->id)
     ->update(array('status' => 'clicked', 'member_id' => $member->id));__  so I guess the database is in tact

Comment: Is the record soft-deleted (i.e. is `deleted_at` non-NULL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find(1)` doesn't mean "give me the first record", it means "give me the first record where id = 1". If you don't have a record with an id of 1, `find(1)` is going to return `null`. When you try and set an attribute on `null`, you get a PHP warning message "Creating default object from empty value".

If you really just want to get the first record, you would use the `first()` method:

```
$invitation = \App\Model\MemberInvitation::first();
```

If you need to get a record with a specific id, you can use the `find()` method. For example, to translate your working DB code into Eloquent, it would look like:

```
$invitation = \App\Model\MemberInvitation::find($member_invitation->id);
$invitation->status = 'clicked';
$invitation->member_id = $member->id;
$invitation->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$invitation = MemberInvitation::findOrFail(1);
$invitation->status = 'clicked';
$invitation->save();
```

If that doesnt work, please show your model

Comment: I'm getting "ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 125: No query results for model [App\Model\MemberInvitation]." -- how can this be if the \DB::table approach works?

Comment: the model class is simple and quite empty: class MemberInvitation extends Model {

 protected $fillable = [];

 /**
  * The database table used by the model.
  *
  * @var string
  */
 protected $table = 'member_invitations';
}

Comment: I suspect your row is soft deleted by having a non-null value in the `deleted_at` column.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is obvious based on your reply from May 15th.

Your "fillable" attribute in the model is empty. Make sure you put "status" in that array. Attributes that are not in this array cannot up modified.